# Different behavior of navbar on different pages

Tags: javascript, css, navbar

I am teaching myself how to make a website and am currently having the following problem:
I have an external file containing my navbar that I included on all pages. I want it to have a fixed position on all pages except on index where I want it sticky on scroll (I have a header above it). I made two css classes and they work as I want them to, but I have no idea how to give it one class on a page and one on the others. Help? (I'm guessing javascript maybe, but how?). Thanks!

Comment: Are you using any frameworks like React or something? if not then how is your navbar in one file? Are you using PHP or any other language?

Comment: Don’t switch classes on the navbar element itself, but on a parent element (such as body or html), and then use the descendant combinator … https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors

Comment: Yes, I am using php

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you don't have other specific ways to detect on which page you are, you can get current URL like this:

```
const currentHref = window.location.href;
```

And then you can apply class, depending on which URL is active:

```
const target = document.getElementById('target-id');

if (currentHref.includes('/page-one')) {
  target.classList.add('class-one');
} else if (currentHref.includes('/page-two')) {
  target.classList.add('class-two');
}
```

It's a simplified version, may be you will need some additions or changes for your real case, but it should provide you the understanding of how to achieve that.